# When I connect a Github repo in azure devops pipeline, does it pull the latest code from git every time a build is triggered in azure pipeline?

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

When I connect a Github repo in azure devops pipeline, does it pull the latest code from git every time a build is triggered?

As I want the pipeline to fetch the latest code from git every time the build is triggered

Comment: That depends on the command you are running. Why not try it out to see what happens?

Comment: I'm new to this, I just pointed the pipeline to a Github Repo and authenticated it with username and PAT. Then I mentioned the path of pom.xml file in the project. This is what I have done until now

Comment: And is there anything not working witn that?

Comment: When I trigger the build it works fine. I just want to understand whether pipeline will pull latest code from git when ever build in triggered or do I have to make a setup for it